# show custom messages is not working properly

Tags: laravel

I have this validation rules where I want to show some custom messages instead of the custom messages. But like below is not working the validation messages appear like:

```
The participant.1.name field is required.
The participant.1.surname field is required.
```

But it should appear like:

```
The field name is required
The field surname is required
```

Validation rules:

```
  $this->validate($request,
            [
                'participant.*.name' => 'required|string',
                'participant.*.surname' => 'required|string',
            ],
            [
                'participant.*.name' => 'The field name is required.',
                'participant.*.name' => 'Please insert a text value for the name field.',
                'participant.*.surname' => 'The field surname is required',
                'participant.*.surname' => 'Please insert a text value for the surname field'
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Are you passing multiple name or surname?

Comment: No, only one name and surname, but with multiple name and surnames also shows the same messages. But in this case like "The participant.1.name field is required.
The participant.2.name field is required.
The participant.1.surname field is required.
The participant.2.surname field is required.
".

Comment: Try 'participant.*.name.required' => 'Your custom message'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your validation messages, For more details,

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Also, please try this,

```
$messages = [
    'participant.1.name.required' => 'The Participant name is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: Thanks, can  you explain for example for the name what should be inside the foreach? Because that code is to get all messages associated with the errors right? But what is necessary is to change that messages.

Comment: I updated solution, pls try this. I hope this will help.